# Change Password Delphi v7

Tags: delphi, passwords, delphi-7

Delphi v7

This code is designed to allow the user to change his password. It appears to execute correctly, but the new password is not saved in the the password data field. I must have done something wrong, but I cannot see it.

```
procedure TForm4.btnPswordClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: integer;
begin
tblLogin.First;;
for I := 0 to tblLogin.RecordCount  do
Begin
If tblLogin.FieldByName('Username').Value = Edit1.Text then
if tblLogin.FieldByName('Password').Value = Edit2.Text  then
sign2.Visible := True; //Test in this case tells the application to make Label1  
visible if the //username and password are correct
tblLogin.Next;
end;
I:= I+1;  //ends search loop of records so program can move on
If sign2.Visible = False then
begin
MessageDlg('Error Username, or Password not correct',
mtConfirmation, [mbCancel], 0);
end
else
if edit3.Text <> edit4.Text  then
begin
MessageDlg('Error New Password does not match',
mtConfirmation, [mbCancel], 0);
end
else
begin
tblLogin.Edit;
tblLogin.FieldByName('Password').Value := Edit3.Text;
tblLogin.Post;
//form1.Show;
//form4.Close;
end;
```

Comment: Maybe indenting your code sensibly would help you see it.

Comment: @Robert, don't forget to accept answers that help you to resolve your questions [`this way`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541). You can also vote for them using the up arrow above the accept check box as a reward ;-)

Answer (score 8):

My comment about formatting your code was just me being snide, but in fact I think it really *would* have helped you find the error yourself. Properly indented, your first loop is this:

```
tblLogin.First;;
for I := 0 to tblLogin.RecordCount  do
Begin
  If tblLogin.FieldByName('Username').Value = Edit1.Text then
    if tblLogin.FieldByName('Password').Value = Edit2.Text  then
      sign2.Visible := True; //Test in this case tells the application to make Label1 visible if the
                             //username and password are correct
  tblLogin.Next;
end;
```

The next line of code is this:

```
I:= I+1;  //ends search loop of records so program can move on
```

The comment suggests that you expect that line to cause the loop to terminate. But that line *isn't in the loop*. If it were in the loop, your code never would have compiled because you're not allowed to modify the loop-control variable inside a loop. Even outside the loop, the compiler should have warned you that the current value of `I` is undefined. That's because the compiler makes no guarantees about the final value of a loop-control variable once the loop has terminated. Adding 1 to an undefined value is still an undefined value.

Furthermore, your loop iterates over more records than your database table contains. If the upper bound of a `for` loop hasn't had 1 subtracted from it and isn't the result of `High` or `Pred`, then you're *probably* doing something wrong.

Since your `I+1` line doesn't actually terminate the loop, you end up traversing all the way to the end of the table, so when you call `tblLogin.Edit`, you're putting the *final* record into edit mode, not the record with the matching account details.

Fixing the indentation will also show that you didn't even include all the code for that function. There's a `begin` without a matching `end` somewhere.

You could avoid all this code by using a single `UPDATE` statement on your database:

```sql
UPDATE tblLogin SET Password = ? WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?
```

Comment: So, my cover is blown. I am not a very good programmer :-) I am actually a Deputy Sheriff trying to create tools to help us do what it is we do. I come her to learn and I appreciate your input. What you suggested is a bit difficult for me to understand, but now I have a place to start and I'll figure it out.

Comment: +1. @Robert, start by turning on hints and warnings (`Project->Options, Delphi Compiler, Hints and Warnings` in recent Delphi versions). The compiler will give you lots of information if you read them. :)

Comment: I indented my code, turned on Hints and Warnings (H/W), edited out all the H/W and now there are no more H/W. Still working on updating the database.

Comment: +1 and by the way, I don't remember if this was in D7, but in at least D2010 and above, you can go to `Edit > Format Source` to format it for you to the recommended formatting.

Comment: I looked, but it is not available id D7. I will learn more doing it myself anyway. Thanks

Comment: I understand the syntax:

    UPDATE tblLogin SET Password = ? WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?

I am not sure where to put it, or what event to attach it to.

I am not sure where to put it, or what event to attach it to.  I have written all this in a buttonclick. Do I add the update within that event?

Comment: @Robert, you'd need to be using a query instead of a table; I'm not sure what type of table you're using, because you don't show any variable declarations. We're presuming that `tblLogin` refers to a `TTable`, `TAdoTable`, or `TIBTable`; what Rob suggested was SQL, which requires either a `TQuery`, `TAdoQuery`, or `TIBQuery` and a database engine that supports SQL. The `?` are parameters, meaning that you'd need to assign them values before executing the SQL. It doesn't really apply to your code, and Rob should have either not mentioned it or should have explained.

Comment: @Robert: Yeah, your cover may be blown, but in this case that is a good thing! Plenty of people here willing to help and willing to go the extra mile when they know it is a newbie asking instead of someone "who sh/could know better and seems too l... to scratch his own back". So be proud of being smart enough to know when to get help and don't hide your "newbie-ness".